# Difference between int and NSInteger for my post

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Here I brought some of the doubt when I used to learn Objective-C and I have searched Google not able to get the perfect answer. I did this from one blog for beginners for Objective-C.

First I will show my code:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textfield 1;
@synthesize textfield 2;
@synthesize textfield 3;
@synthesize totalTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.title = @“calculate the 3 field“;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    int firstNumber = [[self.textfield 1 text] intValue];
    int secondNumber = [[self.textfield 2 text] intValue];
    int thirdNumber = [[self.textfield 3 text] intValue];

    //NSLog(@"firstNumber: %i , secondNumber: %i, thirdNumber: %i", firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber);
    float total = (CGFloat) firstNumber/2 + secondNumber/2 + thirdNumber/2;
    NSLog(@“total is: %f", total);
    NSString *mark = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", total];
    self.totalTextField.text = mark;
}
```

**Explaniation:**

I have three text field called `textfield 1,textfield 2,textfield 3`. When the user enters a number in the three text fields they have to press the calculate button. After that some calculation will go and display the final result in `totalTextField`.

My questions:

1. Why in Xcode the default files called `Appdelegate, view controller.`? What is the actual meaning for that two? Why they are default and what will happen if we remove `Appdelegate.h .m` files? What is the meaning for `viewcontroller, Appdelegate`?
2. In my above code they use inside calculate button method:

   ```
   int firstNumber = [[self.textfield 1 text] intValue];
   ```

   why they din't use:

   ```
   NSInteger * soemname = // alloc init //
   ```
3. And also they used `float`. Why can't use `CGFloat`?

Can any one tell me why they used `int` instead of `NSInteger` and all? And if it is possible can any one recode that `int` with `NSInteger` to work as same?

Please help me to clear this doubt. I am newbie in learning process.

Comment: In the future, try to ask one question per question. It's easier for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**  `AppDelegate` is the default implementation of a delegate class for `UIApplication`.  For details on what the delegate is for, see the documentation for `UIApplication` and `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.  `ViewController` is the name given to a `UIViewController` subclass that several of the templates create for you when you create a new project.  View Controllers are the classes that manage an app's UI.

**2.**  `NSInteger` is an `int` that changes bit-width, depending on platform.  For iOS, this means that it's either 32 bits wide (older hardware) or 64 (newer hardware).  `int` is always 32-bits wide on iOS.  The reason to use one over the other depends on the scenario.  Sometimes it's better to have a known width that won't change.  Sometimes it's better to go with the "native" integer size.  There's no hard and fast rule for picking one over the other.

**3.** `float` is the basic C type.  `CGFloat` is platform-dependent, and the primitive type may change (float, double).  There's little reason to use `CGFloat` unless one is interacting with Core Graphics in some way.